# sharePoint 2013 automatically created new "Local SharePoint sites" content source

Tags: 2013, search

I have created a new Search  managed service, and I define the search source to be **`http://hostname:portnumber`**. But SharePoint 2013 automatically created a new content source named “Local SharePoint sites”so why did SP created this search source? And when/why it created this?

Answer (score 1):

When you provisioned the Search Service Application SharePoint created the Local SharePoint Sites content source for you and added start addresses for existing Web Applications. As you create new web applications SharePoint will add those to the Local SharePoint Sites content source.

Comment: thanks for the reply , but in this way i might have the same source defined twice inside two different services ; the one i create and the local sharePoint sites service ?

Comment: No, when you bind the Web Application to an SSA, SharePoint should only add the web app to the one SSA, not both.